# How to make VSE render faster?

Tags: performance, video-sequence-editor

I'm putting together a video from the VSE. In the sequencer window it is rendering and scrubbing at near realtime yet during output it is taking around 3x longer.

The frames are taking 0.13 seconds each whilst the CPU is only utilised around 20%. I am rendering onto an SSD and using H.264 format 1280x720. Tile size options etc appear to have no or very little effect.

In short - is there any method to speed up the rendering of frames from the VSE?

Comment: the blender VSE is not multi-threaded like rending in cycles might be

Comment: @Vadar, this isnt right, the sequencer has the ability to do threaded per-fetching.

Comment: @ideasman42 I just tired you answer. I am not getting a huge speed up. I am still wrong though and you are still right. But it is not %100

Comment: You may be seeing an FFmpeg limitation, which is what blender uses to compress the video stream. v0.7.x normally only uses one thread. While v2.x uses more than one thread, I'm not sure that blender enables multi threading with ffmpeg, or that it fully supports ffmpeg 2.x yet.

Comment: There are some suggestions in this answer: [how-to-speed-up-blender-video-sequence-editor-rendering](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27007/how-to-speed-up-blender-video-sequence-editor-rendering)

Comment: Could try rendering using a console (no gui) as this means the OS only draws text, not a whole screen with a screen manager, giving blender more cpu power

Comment: I've made a video about VSE performance problems: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6PD6Zsh1bo

I use Pulverize to deal with this, but it's still very sub-optimal, as I have big trouble editing my footage with 1 FPS preview or worse.

Answer (score 17):

#### Update:

Multithreaded VSE rendering is now natively implemented in blender (since around 2.8 or 2.9), which makes this project kind of obsolete, but for more fine grained control of resources (background rendering, utilizing multiple machines) it can still be useful.

---

#### tl;dr: Open source program for automated solution is at the bottom of the post. Latest [release](https://github.com/Isti115/BlenderRenderController/releases/tag/0.4) as well as usage instruction can be found at the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/Isti115/BlenderRenderController):

---

### Problem

I was looking for a free (and maybe even open-source) video editor, and after using it for a while I found out that Blender is very capable of this task, but I was facing the same problem with the unused resources during exporting the finished file. I was searching everywhere, but I couldn't find anything about speeding up the Video Sequence Editor (VSE) rendering that would work for me.

### Solution

After thinking for a while and trying out things I realized that I can run multiple renders at once from the command line, and it seems like the performance scales pretty much linearly with the number of instances running. Of course until you reach the limit of your processor or the amount of RAM you have. (I was running at 87% CPU and 89% of the memory filled, and I wouldn't recommend going higher, because if one of the rendering processes fail to allocate more memory it will crash and you have to do that part over again.)

[image: Running a render in this configuration.]

After you have the parts/chunks of rendered video, you can put it together using the concatenation functionality of ffmpeg. I tried it with `mp4 [H.264]` and `avi [Xvid]`, so I can confirm that those are working, but there might be other formats that can be used, but I haven't experimented with those yet.

### Code parts

I don't have time to do a full tutorial now, but if anybody will show interest I might get around to putting together something.

For this to work you need to have the blender and ffmpeg executables in your PATH environmental variable, and the project file needs to be in the current working directory of the command window.
The code parts I finally ended up writing and using were these:

```
blender -b "name_of_project.blend" -E BLENDER_RENDER -s 0 -e 1000 -a
```

to render one chunk of video. (You can try changing `BLENDER_RENDER` to `CYCLES` if that works better for you, and you have to replace the `0` and `1000` with the actual frame range you want to render. I had quite good results with doing it in chunks of 1000 frames and having around 4-6 processes running at once.)

You have to have multiple CMD windows open at once (unless you write a program to automate it), and you need to call them with different frame ranges.
(I would suggest 0 - 1000; 1001 - 2000; 2001 - 3000; ...)
[The frame range is inclusive, so pay attention not to write the ending number as the beginning number for the next process.]

You have to set the output properties in the Blender rendering setting while the project is open, but you can close the window afterwards. I think you can also set memory limit for the individual processes in Blender at File -> User Preferences -> System -> Memory Cache Limit, but I am not entirely sure about what that does.

For generating the list with the filenames I used PowerShell:

```
dir -n *.mp4 | %{"file '" + $_ + "'"} | Set-Content parts.txt
```

And for joining them I called ffmpeg (also from PowerShell, but this should work from CMD too.)

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i parts.txt -c copy ../output.mp4
```

This seems to be almost instantaneous, so you don't even really need to count this into your rendering time. It puts the resulting video in the parent directory so it doesn't get mixed into the video parts.
(If you used `avi`, you only need to change the extension of the output file and this should work.)

I hope that I could help somebody!

### Sources

My main sources for the Blender command line options were these sites:
https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/command_line.html
https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Reference/Command_Line

And for the joining of the files using ffmpeg:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate
https://superuser.com/questions/607383/concat-two-mp4-files-with-ffmpeg-without-losing-quality/607384
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186500/howto-merge-two-avi-files-using-ffmpeg

---

***Edit 2:***
[Version v0.4](https://github.com/Isti115/BlenderRenderController/releases/tag/0.4) has been released with the contributions of [RedRaptor93](https://github.com/RedRaptor93/BlenderRenderController/).

***Edit:***

### Program

I wrote a very basic application for the purpose of automating this process, that GitHub user [MeTwentyFive](https://github.com/MeTwentyFive) very generously took upon and updated, so now it's more convenient and less buggy.

I have the code of that publicly accessible here:
https://github.com/Isti115/BlenderRenderController

I also included an executable in the [release](https://github.com/Isti115/BlenderRenderController/releases/tag/0.2) of the package, but for that to work you need to have the main `blender.exe` file accessible from the `PATH` environmental variable for rendering, and the same thing holds true with `ffmpeg.exe` for concatenating the parts.

If you need any help modifying, compiling or using it then feel free to message me!

ps.: You can get ffmpeg from here: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html
And I assume that you already have blender, since you are here asking questions about it. ;)

---

***Edit 3:***
Mikeycal Meyers wrote his own python script as a cross-platform solution for the problem.
You can find his explanation about it here:
https://youtu.be/rgwP5L1bICk
and the actual project here:
https://github.com/mikeycal/the-video-editors-render-script-for-blender
Make sure to check his work out as well, and help him improve it if you know some python! ;)

Comment: I have started writing a small C# application to automate this process, so if somebody is interested, I can make a simple user guide for it and post it here. :)

Comment: amazing, thank you for your application now convert my videos in half the time

Comment: I am really glad that I have helped you! Thank you very much for letting me know! :) It makes me feel that it was worth posting it here!

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen to date when researching how to encode long videos faster.  I did this with avi / h.264 / aac and checked the split points after the ffmpeg copy: seamless.

1) I wonder if it is better to split at gop boundaries?
2) Since I mix animations, overlays, blending throughout my files, I also wonder if it is better to keep to the 1000 frame 'chunks' or something like that so one CPU isn't left running for too long over a complex scene while the other tasks finish.

Comment: @jtmcdole: Sadly as I'm not an expert in video editing, I cannot really answer your first question, and for the second, I think that it really depends on the length of your video and your rendering machine's capabilities, but now, that MeTwentyFive has fixed the glitchy audio at merges I think that there is no reason to use too long chunks.

Comment: Also, I'm mentioning @Moliveira too, so he gets notified about the update! ;)
[Download link is in the main post.]

Comment: Its excellent idea and I like you are working on the tool but unfortunately I cannot get it to work. I set for example start: 1, end 100, total frames 1000, select .blend file and output folder and hit Render All. Then it starts to render via one Blender instance and I can see the video file is repeatedly overwritten until the process reach the last chunk. Then the video contain only that last chunk.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Got it! The ouput file name must not be set in Blender, so it generates files with frame numbers! Now it works - excellent! Only the Mixdown feature does not work.

Comment: @JanKadeřábek I'm glad you figured it out! :) About the mixdown: for it to work you need the "Scripts" folder that you can get from the repository. Put it next to the exe file, and it should work, but I found that it wasn't very intuitive (also, I looked at the code and realized that it doesn't work under every circumstance), so I'm currently working on a newer release that will include that and other modifications from a new pull request by RedRaptor93. ps.: Don't forget to upvote if it works for you! ;)

Comment: Upvoted as this is really useful tool / answer. Looking forward to new release! Then I will miss only an ability to change a text font in VSE :)

Comment: @lsti115 If I can have a great feature request - would be possible to get your tool work with OpenGL Render? I use it a lot for its speed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One common reason for the sequencer to slow down is editing video at a different resolution, for fast editing make sure the input and output sizes are the same. *(even one pixel difference will make a significant slowdown)*

### Update, Prefetch option has been removed:

> Another way to speed up things is by enabling pre-fetch frames: *****
>
> `User Prefs -> System -> Sequencer/Clip Editor`
>
> This will use multiple threads to evaluate frames in advance.
>
> If you have enough memory you could also increase the cache limit, which is accessed from the same place.
>
> ---
>
> Warning: There is a bug with *pre-fetch* which is why its disabled by default, any animated sequence strip values (animated opacity for example), won't be correctly taken into account when pre-fetching, however this may not be important in many cases, and crossfades avoid this issue. Just worth noting.
>
> The pre-fetch option was added before Blender's animation system re-write, and the 2 don't work correctly together.

Comment: More interested to speed up the file output (ie saving the video frames). Sequencer editor window is already running at near full speed.

Comment: @Rhys these speedups apply to rendering too.

Comment: May the prefetch not be at this position any more in current Blender releases? You have a Pre-Fetch option per strip now!?!

Comment: Prefetch option is now removed, edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have been having the same problem and I found that changing

```
User Prefs -> System -> Images Draw Method
```

to "GLSL" or "DrawPixels" from "2D Texture" about doubled my VSE render speed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Pulverize to do multi-process rendering from Blender's Video Sequence Editor:

https://github.com/sciactive/pulverize

This will divide the rendering time of your project by the number of CPU cores you have.

(This is like Isti115's program, but it runs on Linux.)

Comment: Nice to see that this approach is made available on other platforms too! :)

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth I wrote a small addon `paraller_render.py` (can be found at https://github.com/elmopl/ktba/) that lets you easily select how many instances of Blender in parallel it should launch and into how many parts to split your video.

To install simply download file from `addons/parallel_rende.py` and put it in your Blender's `scripts/addons` directory.
You should be able to enable it in `File` -> `User Perfernces...` -> `Addons` and search for `VSE Parallel Render`.

Once enabled you should be able to just press space in sequencer (or anywhere else really) and search for "Parallel Render" action.

[image]

Note: As it launches other instances of Blender and tells them to load the same file it will use last saved version of your file. So if you want your most recent changes to be reflected in those renders just save your file before launching it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Codeless Solution

**TL;DR**

- When opening a new blender file, on the splash screen, choose "Video Editing," not "General."
- If you've already started video editing with the "General" template, change Properties -> Render Properties -> Color Management -> View Transform from "Filmic" to "Standard"
- If that doesn't work, and you have the correct render output (see next bullet point), try copying and pasting your video strips into a new Blender file, but it has to be in the same window (i.e. press File -> New -> Video Editing rather than opening a new instance of Blender)
- Make sure you have the correct render output (Properties -> Output Properties -> Output):

  - File Format: FFmpeg video
  - Encoding preset: h264 in MP4
  - Encoding -> Audio -> Audio Codec: MP4 or anything else other than "No Audio"

### Choose the correct new file template

For a solution that doesn't involve code and can be done natively inside Blender (at least, it works inside 2.8X), apparently, when you create a new Blender file, if you choose the "General" option on the splash screen or if you just click out of the splash screen (or have disabled it in your preferences), then video editing will render much slower than if you had clicked the "Video Editing" option in the splash screen.

[image: Blender Splash Screen]

I think the reason it's faster to use the "Video Editing" option for video editing is that it changes a few settings by default.  For example, in Properties -> Render Properties -> Color Management, the "View Transform" is set to "Filmic" for "General" and "Standard" for "Video Editing."  In addition, there is no default cube and light in the "Video Editing" template.

### ...or if you've already started

If you've already done a bunch of work editing your video after pressing "General," you can try changing the color management setting I mentioned above from "Filmic" to "Standard."  It worked for me in a test run, but not on a different project.  But you could try it and see if it works.

[image: Blender Color Management]

If that doesn't work, you can try copying all you video/audio strips into a new Blender file.  If you try copying them from one window to another, it won't work.  But if you copy them, save your Blender file, and then go into File -> New -> Video Editing, then you will be able to paste the video/audio strips.

### Change the render output settings

Finally, make sure you're render output it set correctly.  Rendering to image files is safer because, if blender crashes, you can easily reopen the blender file and continue rendering.  But rendering to image files is slower than rendering to video files, and for short renders in the Video Editor, it's best to render to a video file.  I usually use the "FFmpeg video" File Format.

[image]

Then use the "h264 in MP4" preset for the encoding.

[image]

Just remember to expand the "Encoding" section, look under the "Audio" section, and change the "Audio Codec" from "No Audio" to "MP3" or whatever audio format you want to use.

[image]

And here are all the settings together in one shot:

[image]

Those settings usually give me approximately realtime rendering for simple video tracts (I think image sequences are actually slower, but I'm not 100% sure).  Note that the render preview will skip frames, so it will still look choppy, but if you check the frame number that it's rendering, you should see it skipping along pretty quickly.

Comment: thanks! changing view transform to standard did the trick. the images were really helpful.

Comment: thanks! Filmic to Standard seems to half my rendering time!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single very scary command line which does incremental, parallel, resumable renders on Linux --- and it ought to work on Windows to if you have Cygwin.

`` seq 3041 75966 | parallel --joblog joblog -X -n 20 --eta --bar 'blender -b video.blend -E BLENDER_RENDER --render-frame `echo {} | tr " " ","`' ``

Replace the two numbers after `seq` with your start and end frames. Replace `video.blend` with your Blender file. Then run, and... hope...

It'll show you a pretty clunky progress bar on the command line which looks like this:

`5% 184:3463=739s 6861 6862 6863 6864 6865 6866 6867 6868 6869 6870 6871 6872`

The `5%` tells you where it's got to, the `184:3463` tells you which batch it's reached and how many are left to go (note that frames are processed in batches controlled by the `-n` argument, and are *not* the same as frame numbers, increasing `-n` will make for slightly more efficient renders), the `=739s` is an estimate of how long there is to go, and be warned that it lies *foully*, and the rest of the numbers indicate frames it's currently rendering.

If you ^C it in the middle, or it dies with lack of disk space or something, you should be able to resume by adding `--resume` after the `parallel`, and it should automatically pick up from where it left off.

Remember to configure for rendering to frames, etc, in the normal way.