# How to set up Blender for Multicore Animation

Tags: rendering, animation

I use Blender as a video editor.

After setting up the video I want to process including correct Start and End frames I click "Properties->Render->Animation".

My CPU usage climbs to a range from 20% to 25%. I am running an i7-3770K @ 3.50 GHz with 32 GB Ram. Blender is working on a physical drive, not an ssd. The i7 has 4 cores. With hyper threading that is 8 Hyper threads. I think Blender is running animation on only one core.

When I try to research this topic I get a mixed message.

I can find performance analysis multi core vs single core. I can find a Microsoft demo how the job queue can be executed parallel on a cloud service.

I can find entries that say the Renderer is multi core the rest is not.

But I can not find the settings to enable my animation to be multi core. I assume this is possible since it looks like it is part of the Renderer .

Is there something definitive like an official source on this?
How do I set up my Renderer so that It utilizes all (or most) of my machine?

Comment: When you say "After setting up the video I want to process" does this mean you are using blender's video editor (VSE) or are you rendering a 3D scene?

Comment: @RayMairlot Setting up the video means that I drag and drop an avi file onto the Video sequence editor. When that is done I change the endframe to fit the video. Other settings were stored in my preferences. Not sure if that is the VSE Editor or not but it is not a 3D Scene.

Comment: VSE = Video Sequence Editor.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-to-make-vse-render-faster

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the current VSE targets in the [road map](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sobotka/VSE/VSE_Roadmap_Discussion) do not include multithreading. That may change in the future.

The underlying issue of slow rendering is solved in [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-to-make-vse-render-faster).