# Blender 2.79b not using full AMD GPU (RX550)

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, video, gpu

**I think I may have solved the problem. GPU Usage is still really low but buffering is much better after creating a proxy for the video stipe.**

I am having an issue rendering & skimming through video on my machine. I have a 7th gen i5, 8GB ram, SSD & an AMD Rx550 GPU.

The problem is that when I try to render video it is really slow. Skimming through the timeline is also slow (around 18 fps @ 1080p).

When I look at the GPU usage in wattsman it is literally at idle. Sometimes it goes up to like 300+ mhz which is still nothing.

**What I have already done**
- I have gone into settings and enabled OpenCL computing and set the RX550 as the device.
- Changed ram to use 4000.
- Changed from blender render to Cycles Render (this improved performance a bit but still the GPU doesn't seem to be used.
- Changed

I am out of ideas on what the problem is. I would appreciate any help you guys can offer.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For video editing blender is very basic, and certainly not the most efficient. It lags light years behind other video editing apps that are GPU accelerated. Try resolve free, shotcut, Avid media composer first, or any of the paid apps like resolve, vegas, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed it lags a lot but I have figured out how to make it work for my needs by watching a few tutorials on youtube. It definitely is not very user-friendly. Thank you for the recommendations, I'll definitely have to check out those other video editors and see which one works best.

Comment: I have a Ryzen 7 and a GTX1060  and VSE is still causing me a crippling depression. It isn't your RX550. [Apparently a solution is to use multiple blender calls to render a frame, for now.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-to-make-vse-render-faster)