# The movie slows down

Tags: rendering

[image]

[image]

Hi
I am trying to edit this clip. It starts off ok. As you can see, the top left of the first picture got WHITE fps reading (around 30) and the speed of the movement is fine. But within seconds it changes (second picture). fps goes down to about 15 (number changes to RED) and the movie slows down for the rest of the clip. 
The clip was taken with a mobile phone.
Can you please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: This is not abnormal. The original VSE has a poor hardware optimalization but there are a few solution to earn better performance: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-to-make-vse-render-faster/44906#44906

Comment: Thanks FFeller, I will do that.