# Terrible VSE output performance when rending

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, performance, hardware

I use Blender as VSE.

I was going to edit some clips. my setting is in screenshot.

Blender version: 2.81a, download from Steam.

OS: Win7-64bit

My Hardware:

- i7-4790k with 16G memory
- Nvidia Geforce GTX1080

I just cut a video into 3 pieces, removed the middle one, and removed the gap. No other effects, nor anything else.

[image: use as vse]

When I click **Render Animation**, the preview window pop out. It is terribly slow, like under 15fps. My outbut should be generated as 60fps, means a 5mins video needs 20mins to render. That performance is horrible to me.

I checked both my CPU usage and my GPU usage. CPU is used by 20%. None of GPU is used. Both of them are not decently used by rending.

(Drivers are correctly installed because I can use NVENC by using Avidemux, and also games)

What should I do to get a good performance when using Blender as VSE?

[image: cycles render devices]
[image: output]
[image: output2]

Comment: As you can see, Blender's VideoSequencer rendering capabilities are very bad. They are also single threaded, the slow speed is coming the design, there may not be much that you can do.

Comment: Split render between multiple Blender app instances by frame ranges and then with ffmpeg's *concatenate* function join cuts. Yep, it sounds like a big pain, but it's not... that big. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-to-make-vse-render-faster and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-to-make-vse-render-faster?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I have read those two posts before this. Seems I have to change to another NLE.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Parallel Render add-on: https://github.com/elmopl/ktba/blob/master/scripts/addons/parallel_render.py

Use it like this way:
https://github.com/elmopl/ktba/wiki/Addons

Comment: Seems not support Blender 2.8. I can't find 'VSE Parallel Render' that wiki says.

Comment: After installation you should be able to find it in the Properties/Render panel.

Comment: My biggest question is: How to install it. That wiki said nothing with installation.